# Unable to ping Ubuntu Virtual Machine in another laptop using Oracle VM VirtualBox

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

I'm using Oracle VM VirtualBox 7.0.6 to run an Ubuntu 22.04 Virtual Machine on my Windows 11 host operating system. I have a separate Ubuntu 22.04 Virtual Machine running on another laptop, and I'm trying to ping it from my VM. However, I always receive a "No route to host" error.

I have already tried using a host-only adapter in VirtualBox to enable communication between the VMs, but it didn't work. I also made sure that the firewall on the Virtual Machine is disabled.

I have searched for solutions online, but most of the results discuss transferring data between a VM and the host machine or between VMs within the same system. I couldn't find any information on how to ping a VM in another system.

As a beginner in using Virtual Machines, I have limited knowledge about computer networking beyond what I've experimented with while trying to solve this problem.

I would appreciate any guidance on how to establish communication between my Ubuntu VM and the Ubuntu VM in the other laptop. What steps should I follow to enable ping or any other method of communication between the two VMs?

Thank you in advance for your help.